# Time Counter Command giving NaN in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, command

I am trying to make a command that counts the time between 2 commands. Example: `!start` (save the current time) - `!end` (saves the current time and get the difference between 2 commands). The export format of the latest time wants to be an embed that contains something like this: `"Your time: 1:45:32 (hours:minutes:seconds)"`.
Here is my code:

```
    bot.on("message", (message) => {


        var startDate;

        if (message.content == "!start") {
            startDate = new Date();

            console.log(new Date(startDate).getTime())

            message.reply("works");
        }

        if (message.content == "!end") {
            let endDate = new Date();

            
            console.log(new Date(endDate).getTime())


            let result = new Date(startDate).getTime() - new Date(endDate).getTime();


            message.reply(result)
        }
    });
```

The message that this code sends is "NaN"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bot is responding with `NaN` (which stands for **N**ot **a** **N**umber) probably because `startDate` is `undefined`, which means:

- `new Date(startDate)` is an invalid date
- `new Date(startDate).getTime()` is `NaN`
- `new Date(startDate).getTime() - new Date(endDate).getTime()` is `NaN` (`NaN - anything` is always `NaN`)
- `result`, which is `NaN`, gets coerced to a string and the message `'NaN'` is sent.

What most likely happened is that a user sent `!end` before `!start`, so `startDate` is uninitialised.

To fix this, check if `startDate` is defined before continuing with the `!end` command:

```js
if (message.content == "!end") {
    if (!startDate) return message.reply('Use !start first')

    // rest of code...
}
```

For more information on `NaN`, see [`NaN` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

---

Some other things:

- You don't need to use `new Date(startDate)` or `new Date(endDate)`; `startDate` and `endDate` are already `Date`s.
- Let's say someone sends `!start` and then `!end`. What happens if someone sends
  `!end` again? The bot would respond with the time since the `!start` to the last `!end`, which is probably unintended. You might want to set `startDate` to `undefined` after the `!end` command to reset it.
- This command works across channels (someone can send `!start` in one channel and `!end` in another). If you don't want this, you could try storing the dates in something like a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) keyed by the channel IDs. (EDIT: it would probably be better to keep the timers unique per user, not per channel.)

Here's how I would implement it:

```js
/**
 * A map from user IDs to start timestamps
 * @type Map<string, number>
 */
const startTimestamps = new Map()

/**
 * Pads a number to 2 digits.
 * @param {number} value
 * @returns {string}
 */
const pad2Digits = value => String(value).padStart(2, '0')

bot.on('message', async message => {
  try {
    if (message.content === '!start') {
      // Sets the start time. This overrides any existing timers
      // Date.now() is equivalent to new Date().getTime()
      startTimestamps.set(message.author.id, Date.now())
      await message.reply('Timer started.')
    } else if (message.content === '!end') {
      if (startTimestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        // The user has an existing timer to stop
        // Calculate the timer result
        const ms = Date.now() - startTimestamps.get(message.author.id)
        const totalSecs = Math.floor(ms / 1000)
        const totalMins = Math.floor(totalSecs / 60)
        const hrs = Math.floor(totalMins / 60)
        const mins = totalMins % 60
        const secs = totalSecs % 60
        // Reply with result
        await message.reply(`Your time: ${hrs}:${pad2Digits(mins)}:${pad2Digits(secs)}`)
        // Remove timestamp from map
        startTimestamps.delete(message.author.id)
      } else {
        // The user does not have an existing timer
        await message.reply('You need to use `!start` first!')
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
})
```

Comment: could you please make an other answer and upload tha code that u would use to do what i am trying to do? Btw i send the !start before !end so that isn't the problem

Comment: @CakeDevelopment I updated my answer. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: @CakeDevelopment You’re welcome! If this answer helped you, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the check mark. This indicates to the system and other users that this question has been answered. You also get some reputation! See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: could you please make an other edit for me and show me how i could change the code so it keeps the WHOLE time that a user spent like: ex. your time is 4:23:31 and your total time spent is 26:25:04 i would be very glad if u could show me that :) and also could you please tell me if the map resets when i restart the bot and if yes how would i make the bot keep data forever?

Comment: @CakeDevelopment That seems like another question. Feel free to ask another question, use the [official Discord.js guide on databases](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize), or have a look at [some other StackOverflow questions about using databases with discord.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+discord.js+database).